# Screenshots in X11

Tags: c++, linux, desktop, x11, xlib

What functions would one use to take a screenshot of an X11 desktop, using the Xlib library? I would prefer a method that's more efficient than getting individual pixels. **Thanks.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard tool for taking screenshots in X11 is to use

```
xwd -root > myscreen.xwd
```

Then, convert to .pnm with

```
xwd2pnm myscreen.xwd > myscreen.pnm
```

Therefore, you can locate the source code of xwd and see how it is implemented,
http://cvsweb.xfree86.org/cvsweb/xc/programs/xwd/xwd.c?rev=HEAD&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-markup

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it uses XmuClientWindow to take the actual screenshot, which is an X11 extension.

Comment: @myrkos: That's a function for finding windows. Screen dumping is done with the `XGetImage` function.

Comment: It's not that different, but the source for the xwd shipped in current distros is at:  http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xwd/tree/