# Screenshot Taker on Windows 7 (or any platform, if possible) using C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to code a program in C++ that takes screenshots and saves them. Can you suggest any sources to refer to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to take screenshots of a Window with C++ in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531684/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-a-window-with-c-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen several applications of this nature. Don't forget to include your platform.

http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/22809-screenshot-c/
[Screenshots in X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293525/screenshots-in-x11)

Several things pop up instantly from **Google** =]